# job hangs when using pipe() with reduceByKey()

Tags: apache-spark

I meet a situation: 
When I use

```
val a = rdd.pipe("./my_cpp_program").persist() 
a.count()  // just use it to persist a 
val b = a.map(s => (s, 1)).reduceByKey().count()
```

it 's so fast

but when I use

```
val b = rdd.pipe("./my_cpp_program").map(s => (s, 1)).reduceByKey().count()
```

it is so slow.... 
and there are many such log in my executors:

```
15/10/31 19:53:58 INFO collection.ExternalSorter: Thread 78 spilling in-memory map of 633.1 MB to disk (8 times so far) 
15/10/31 19:54:14 INFO collection.ExternalSorter: Thread 74 spilling in-memory map of 633.1 MB to disk (8 times so far) 
15/10/31 19:54:17 INFO collection.ExternalSorter: Thread 79 spilling in-memory map of 633.1 MB to disk (8 times so far) 
15/10/31 19:54:29 INFO collection.ExternalSorter: Thread 77 spilling in-memory map of 633.1 MB to disk (8 times so far) 
15/10/31 19:54:50 INFO collection.ExternalSorter: Thread 76 spilling in-memory map of 633.1 MB to disk (9 times so far)
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't passed a function to `reduceByKey()`. From the docs for reduceByKey:

> When called on a dataset of (K, V) pairs, returns a dataset of (K, V) pairs where the values for each key are aggregated using *the given reduce function func*, which must be of type (V,V) => V. Like in groupByKey, the number of reduce tasks is configurable through an optional second argument.

In this case, you want to pass the anonymous function `(a, b) => a + b` to aggregate values across your keys (can also be written as `_ + _` using Scala's shortened underscore notation).

Since you are calling `count()` though (which essentially will count the number of unique keys after a `reduceByKey()`), it probably makes sense for you to just use `distinct()` instead. The implementation of distinct is actually very similar to what you're currently trying to do (mapping instead to `(s, null)` and then calling reduceByKey) but from a code readability standpoint, a distinct would better indicate what your end goal is. Something like this would work:

```
val b = rdd.pipe("./my_cpp_program").distinct().count()
```

Since you may actually also be interested in the counts per each unique key, there are other functions in the [`PairRDDFunctions`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala#L382) class that can help out with this. I would check out `countByKey()`, `countByKeyApprox()`, and `countApproxDistinctByKey()`. Each have different use cases but offer interesting solutions to their respective problems.